# Phrase for saying we can only speculate

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, formality

I am looking for a more formal variation of this sentence:

> "We can only speculate at this point."

Perhaps what is taking away from the professional feel that I want is the first person "We."

### Question

Is there a more formal way to express this sentence, ideally by not using "we?"

Comment: Maybe `This is just a hypothesis at this point`

Comment: 'Beyond this point, it's all guesswork.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it in a passive voice:

> "This can only be speculated at this point."

You can check the usage in more formal texts here [site:gov "can only be speculated"](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&authuser=0&ei=LsbjXOPbBsTDwALH9aHYAQ&q=site%3Agov%20%22can%20only%20be%20speculated%22&oq=site%3Agov%20%22can%20only%20be%20speculated%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...41243.47295..47960...1.0..0.64.489.9......0....1..gws-wiz.geqCl9psS6g)

or

> This is only speculation at this point.
>
> This is a matter of speculation at this point.

[site:gov "a matter of speculation at this point"](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&authuser=0&ei=mcrjXLm-HcThkgWpmJHgAg&q=site%3Agov%20%22a%20matter%20of%20speculation%20at%20this%20point%22&oq=site%3Agov%20%22a%20matter%20of%20speculation%20at%20this%20point%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10681.11111..11535...0.0..0.57.169.3......0....1..gws-wiz.eBwn6KZY6Z0)

Comment: "This can only be speculated at this point" uses 'speculate' as a transitive verb with an implied noun/pronoun object in the transposed form ('We can only speculate this'). I can't find a dictionary (CED, ODO, Collins, M-W, AHD, RHK Webster's) licensing this, though admittedly your examples include ... er ... examples. (eg NCBI: 'Other possible mechanisms can only be speculated.')

Answer (score 2):

As in:

"We can only **presume** at this point."

presume    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/presume)

> 1. To take for granted as being true in the absence of proof to the contrary:

Comment: Like in *Presumed Inocent*. Good point!